# SAP HYBRIS - What could be the reasons for a product to be not available for checkout?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to checkout a product and it is not showing- what could be the possible causes as to why the product is not available for checkout?

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible due to couple of reasons as mentioned following:

1- Live Stock isn't available from the backend (SAP/Microsoft NAV/ or any other ERP that is used in your application where all the products are actually managed.)
2- FrontEnd issue.
3- Basket/Cart issue

If you tell us more log stack trace then I could help more in this.

Many Thanks